# Is there a way to simulate WatchConnectivity reachability loss?

Tags: ios, swift, connectivity, watchos, wcsession

I am trying to test my app's functionality for when the watch loses or regains connection with the phone (sessionReachabilityDidChange) and for when I try to send a message and have no connectivity (trying to simulate a sendMessage error.)

Is there a way to do this either through code or on the iPhone/Watch Simulator?  Also is there a way to *simulate* this on the phone itself?  I know I can just turn Bluetooth/Wifi off, but I'd like to be able to do it without losing my debugging connection to the watch.

Comment: I suspect the answer is no, but this is a great question. I would love to see some tools similar to Network Link Conditioner in the simulator or on the actual iOS device that allow testing of various watch connectivity scenarios.